# Mac OS X - How to store web projects in a location other than /Library

Tags: macos, apache, webserver, symlink

Google turns up nothing but very basic set up of web servers on the Mac. I've got that.

I build web projects locally on a Mac using PHP/MySQL. I store the sites in /Library/WebServer/Documents then access them via browsers with http://localhost.

This works fine.

What I would like to do is to be able to place symlinks or aliases of projects into the /WebServer/Documents folder and access sites on other (local) drives. I don't want to have to store everything in the Library folder. However, it seems that symlinks don't work. The only way a project functions is if all it's files are located in the /Library folder - no symlinks.

I realize I can change the root path for the web server in the http.conf file but I don't want to actually change the server path, I merely want to use symlinks if possible. I also realize I could use something like MAMP, but things run fine with my traditional set up (and I prefer to avoid MAMP since it's not always real-world). Main motivation here is that I don't want to store files on the boot volume, where there Library folder is located.

Can I use symlinks for directories with Mac OS10.6.8/Apache? if so how, please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved via this article at Apple:

http://support.apple.com/kb/TA21182?viewlocale=en_US

One must specifically create a symbolic link. Which, it appears, is not the same as an Alias on the Mac OS.

Answer (score -1):

But this isn't feature of MAMP application, this is about web server. Make it through MAMP and go see what is new in apache config files (httpd.conf, vhost.conf).

Comment: Again.. I am not interested in installing and using MAMP. Which may have adverse effects on my traditional web server set up. But thanks.

Answer (score -1):

you have to use symlinks instead of an alias... sad there is no ui for that!

you have to go into the Terminal and type:

```
ln -s /ORIGINALPATH /LINKEDPATH
```

the first PATH is the base path of the original file and the second is for the base path for the symlink of the file/folder etc